# Warning message in Google Bigquery Console after running the code

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

is this how temp table works in bq. i get a warning message that says, "Could not compute bytes processed estimate ". I have  pasted the code as well as the results in bq below.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE Analysis AS
    SELECT
      member_casual,
      month,
      num_month
    FROM (
      SELECT
        member_casual,
        month,
        COUNT(month) as num_month
      FROM
        quick-discovery-402518.cyclistic_project.DataForAnalysis
      GROUP BY
        month,
        member_casual
      ORDER BY
        num_month DESC
    );
    SELECT
      *
    FROM 
      Analysis;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsbMb.png) snapshot of the picture in bq

Comment: Before running a query in the console, an attempt is made to predict how many bytes might need to be scanned to resolve the query.  This is useful information because that can be used to predict the cost of the query.  However, there are times when we can't predict how much data might need to be scanned.  There are many possibilities for this including tables that use external data.  After running the query, you can see how many bytes were actually scanned.

Answer (score 0):

It's called [Dry Run](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries#dry-run) in Bigquery. It is used to estimate the size of data that will be processed if the query is ran.